# Matplotlib: how to add a ytick label (or other label that can do the job) at a given point?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show the result of a PCC test. I have two y axes to show the r and p-value respectively. I plot a horizontal dashed line on the second axis to indicate the threshold value `p=0.05` and I want to add another ytick lable (or other label as long as it's in the right location, such as the red 0.05 in the picture below) to the second y axis while keeping the original ytick labels.

According to matplotlib documentation [Anatomy of a figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/showcase/anatomy.html#anatomy-of-a-figure), I believe `Minor tick label` is what I need, but I haven't found any tutorial on how to achieve what I want.

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
N = 8

ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35

pcc_r_data = feature_i_data[pcc_r]
pcc_p_data = feature_i_data[pcc_p]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_xticks(ind + width / 2,
               ('GSE35570_N', 'GSE35570_P',
                'GSE29265_N', 'GSE29265_P',
                'GSE33630_N', 'GSE33630_P',
                'GSE60542_N', 'GSE60542_P'),
               rotation=-45)
ax1.bar(ind, pcc_r_data, width, label='r', color=sns.color_palette()[0])
ax1.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax1.set_ylabel('r', rotation="horizontal")
ax1.yaxis.set_label_coords(0, 1.03)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.axhline(y=0.05, color='r', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
ax2.bar(ind + width, pcc_p_data, width, label='p-value', color=sns.color_palette()[1])
ax2.set_yscale("log")
ax2.set_ylim([0.00000001, 1])
ax2.set_ylabel('p-value', rotation="horizontal")
ax2.yaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, 1.08)

lines, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, loc='upper right', ncol=2)

fig.suptitle('Pearson correlation coefficient')

plt.show()
```

[image: my_plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a text outside the plot.  The [y-axis transform](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) uses the x-position in "axes coordinates" and the y-position in "data coordinates".

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 8
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax1.set_xticklabels(('GSE35570_N', 'GSE35570_P', 'GSE29265_N', 'GSE29265_P', 'GSE33630_N',
                     'GSE33630_P', 'GSE60542_N', 'GSE60542_P'), rotation=-45)
ax1.bar(ind, np.random.rand(N) ** .2, width, label='r', color=sns.color_palette()[0])
ax1.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax1.set_ylabel('r', rotation="horizontal")
ax1.yaxis.set_label_coords(0, 1.03)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.axhline(y=0.05, color='r', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
ax2.bar(ind + width, np.random.rand(N) ** 5, width, label='p-value', color=sns.color_palette()[1])
ax2.set_yscale("log")
ax2.set_ylim([0.00000001, 1])
ax2.set_ylabel('p-value', rotation="horizontal")
ax2.yaxis.set_label_coords(1.05, 1.08)
ax2.text(1, 0.05, ' 0.05', transform=ax2.get_yaxis_transform(), fontsize=18, color='r', ha='left', va='center')

lines, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, loc='upper right', ncol=2)

fig.suptitle('Pearson correlation coefficient')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: twinx with extra text]

Alternatively, you could set a minor tick with a label:

```py
ax2.set_yticks([0.05], minor=True)
ax2.set_yticklabels([0.05], minor=True, color='r', fontsize=18)
```